# How to filter objects by roles array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array that contains some objects:

```
const array = [
            {
                id: 1,
                username: "username1",
                roles: [
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        name: "ROLE_USER"
                    },
                    {
                        id: 8,
                        name: "ROLE_ADMIN"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                username: "username2",
                roles: [
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        name: "ROLE_USER"
                    },
                    {
                        id: 10,
                        name: "ROLE_TESTER"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                username: "username3",
                roles: [
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        name: "ROLE_USER"
                    },
                    {
                        id: 8,
                        name: "ROLE_ADMIN"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
```

Now, how do I filter these objects by role? I wanted to get users with "ROLE_ADMIN" only. I tried doing something like:

```js
const admins = array.filter(user => user.roles.filter(role => role.name === "ROLE_ADMIN"));
```

and

```js
const admins = array.filter(user => user.roles.map(role => role.name === "ROLE_ADMIN"));
```

and

```js
const admins = array.map(user => user.roles.filter(role => role.name === "ROLE_ADMIN"));
```

but none of these worked. Can someone help me?

Comment: reduce (and some other characters)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to combine `filter` with `some`

According to [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

> The `some()` method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.

Below snippet could help you

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    username: 'username1',
    roles: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'ROLE_USER'
      },
      {
        id: 8,
        name: 'ROLE_ADMIN'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    username: 'username2',
    roles: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'ROLE_USER'
      },
      {
        id: 10,
        name: 'ROLE_TESTER'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    username: 'username3',
    roles: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'ROLE_USER'
      },
      {
        id: 8,
        name: 'ROLE_ADMIN'
      }
    ]
  }
]

const res = data.filter(user =>
  user.roles.some(role => role.name === 'ROLE_ADMIN')
)

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

An empty `array` or `object` will still be truthy in `JavaScript`. Add `.length > 0` for `roles` filter (your first option) as below

```
const admins = array.filter(user => user.roles.filter(role => role.name === "ROLE_ADMIN").length > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`It will return all the users where all the role types are admin

```
`const admins = array.filter(user => {
    return user.roles.every(role => role.name === "ROLE_ADMIN");
})`
```

If you need any one type to be admin inside the roles then :

`const admins = array.filter(user => { return user.roles.some(role => role.name === "ROLE_ADMIN"); })`

Answer (score -4):

You can use this

```
const admins = array.filter(user => user.roles.map(role => role.name).includes( "ROLE_ADMIN"));
```

Comment: Please avoid accusing people. It is not really constructive and can cause fights. On SO in situations like these, we always assume good faith and move on. If you feel like the problem needs to be escalated then please feel free to raise it on [meta].

Answer (score -4):

Untested but should work.

```js
const admins = array.filter(user => user.roles.map(role => role.name ).includes("ROLE_ADMIN"));
```

Comment: Why use map to filter? Wrong method

Comment: care to enlighten me how the answer is wrong? have you tested it with OP's array of users?

Comment: It works, but thats does not mean is correct. MAP, maps object, filter, filters objects. Easy like this...

Comment: Yes. You want to make sure? Create a question and ask if that way of doing is correct. So you won't rely just on my opinion.

Comment: @Kharel please read the [code of conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct)